# Java Play 2.3.8: DataSource user is null? bindFromRequest() does not work properly

Tags: java, html, eclipse, scala, playframework-2.0

I started learning Play this week. Now I am trying to write a Code that creates a session, when a user logs in.
Sorry, but the post looks a bit messy because I am new user, who is not allowed to post pictures.

I am using Java play 2.3.8 and eclipse 4.4.1 (and I already tried the other tips i saw here)

At the moment I always get this errormessage:

> play.api.Application$$anon$1: Execution exception[[RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException]]
>       at play.api.Application$class.handleError(Application.scala:296) ~[play_2.11-2.3.6.jar:2.3.6]
>       at play.api.DefaultApplication.handleError(Application.scala:402) [play_2.11-2.3.6.jar:2.3.6]
>       at play.core.server.netty.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler$$anonfun$3$$anonfun$applyOrElse$4.apply(PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.scala:320) [play_2.11-2.3.6.jar:2.3.6]
>       at play.core.server.netty.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler$$anonfun$3$$anonfun$applyOrElse$4.apply(PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.scala:320) [play_2.11-2.3.6.jar:2.3.6]
>       at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:145) [scala-library-2.11.1.jar:na]
>   Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>       at play.data.Form.bind(Form.java:394) ~[play-java_2.11-2.3.6.jar:2.3.6]
>       at play.data.Form.bindFromRequest(Form.java:221) ~[play-java_2.11-2.3.6.jar:2.3.6]
>       at controllers.Application.authenticate(Application.java:70) ~[classes/:na]
>       at Routes$$anonfun$routes$1$$anonfun$applyOrElse$11$$anonfun$apply$11.apply(routes_routing.scala:209) ~[classes/:na]
>       at Routes$$anonfun$routes$1$$anonfun$applyOrElse$11$$anonfun$apply$11.apply(routes_routing.scala:209) ~[classes/:na]
>   Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: null
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_31]
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_31]
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_31]
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483) ~[na:1.8.0_31]
>       at play.data.Form.bind(Form.java:391) ~[play-java_2.11-2.3.6.jar:2.3.6]
>   Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: DataSource user is null?
>       at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.lib.sql.DataSourcePool.(DataSourcePool.java:204) ~[avaje-ebeanorm-3.3.4.jar:na]
>       at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.core.DefaultServerFactory.getDataSourceFromConfig(DefaultServerFactory.java:419) ~[avaje-ebeanorm-3.3.4.jar:na]
>       at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.core.DefaultServerFactory.setDataSource(DefaultServerFactory.java:385) ~[avaje-ebeanorm-3.3.4.jar:na]
>       at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.core.DefaultServerFactory.createServer(DefaultServerFactory.java:163) ~[avaje-ebeanorm-3.3.4.jar:na]
>       at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.core.DefaultServerFactory.createServer(DefaultServerFactory.java:125) ~[avaje-ebeanorm-3.3.4.jar:na]

This is my method, that is called:

```
public static Result authenticate() {

    Form<Login> loginForm = Form.form(Login.class);

    Login loginUser = loginForm.bindFromRequest().get();


    if (!usersList.getUsers().contains(loginForm)) {
        return ok(login.render("test"));
    } else {
        session().clear();
        session("email", loginForm.get().email);
        System.out.println("ich bin hier");
        return redirect(routes.Application.login());

    }


}
```

This is the model (getters and setters are there, too):

```
public class Login {

public Login(){

}
public String email;
public String password;

public Login(String email, String password){
    this.email=email;
    this.password=password;
}

public String validate() {
    if (Users.authenticate(email, password) == null) {
      return "Invalid user or password";
    }
    return null;
}

public static Finder<String,Login> find = new Finder<String,Login>(
        String.class, Login.class
    );
```

And here the scala.html document:

```
<div class="Login">
   <br>
    <br>
     <br>
      <br>

      <h1>Login</h1>

<form action="@routes.Application.authenticate()" method="post">
 <p><input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" value=""></p>
 <p><input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" value=""></p>
 <p class="submit"><input type="submit" name="Login" value="Login"></p>
</form>
```

And last but not least the error message in my browser says the exception is thrown in line 70:

> [RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException]
>
> System.out.println("nach loginform");
>   68
>   69      //System.out.println(loginForm.bindFromRequest().toString());
>   70      Login loginUser = loginForm.bindFromRequest().get();
>   71
>   72      System.out.println(loginForm.toString());
>   73//        Form loginForm = form(Login.class).bindFromRequest();
>   74
>   75      if (!usersList.getUsers().contains(loginForm)) {

thanks in advance for helping me with this issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you missing something

```
@Entity 
public class Login extends Model {
```

and also check if `ebean.default="models.*"` line is uncommented in `application.conf`